# How to get the value of a nested object containing array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am trying to check if a value is present in the below nested object:

```
var Obj = {
   "testname":"Validator",
   "dataTableName":"y",
   "dataColumnName":"y",
   "CheckFilter":"CheckBoxFilter",
   "CheckFilterSettings":{
      "values":[
         "70.00"
      ],
      "hierarchyPaths":[
         
      ]
   }
}
```

I tried using

```
for (var i in Obj) {
    if (Obj[i].CheckFilterSettings.values[0] === "70.00"){
    console.log("Value Found");
    }else{
        console.log("Value Not Found");
        }
    }
```

Could someone please suggest where I am going wrong.

Comment: what do you really want, check for a value in the array "Obj.CheckFilterSettings.values"?

Answer (score 1):

Your Obj[i] is itself the key, so,  do not call "CheckFilterSettings" on Obj[i] again.

Check this one-

```js
var Obj = {
    "testname": "Validator",
    "dataTableName": "y",
    "dataColumnName": "y",
    "CheckFilter": "CheckBoxFilter",
    "CheckFilterSettings": {
        "values": [
            "70.00"
        ],
        "hierarchyPaths": [

        ]
    }
}

for (var i in Obj) {
    if (Obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        if (i === "CheckFilterSettings" && Obj[i].hasOwnProperty("values")) {
            if (Obj[i].values[0] === "70.00") {
                console.log("Value Found");
            } else {
                console.log("Value Not Found");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check that the `values` array is not empty, and that the path to that array remains constant, you could just use:

```
for (var i in Obj) {
    if (Obj[i].CheckFilterSettings.values.length) {
    console.log("Value Found");
    } else {
        console.log("Value Not Found");
    }
}
```

Note that this assumes an array of objects, which is not evident from the provided data structure. If that's the entire object, then try:

```
if (Obj.CheckFilterSettings.values.length) {
    console.log("Value Found");
} else {
    console.log("Value Not Found");
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. Check - What would `Obj[i]` return? And you're trying to access `CheckFilterSettings` on `Obj[i]`

Comment: Please see the edited post @Tethys0 (I've amended it and added a note).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys()` like this:

```js
let Obj = {
    "testname": "Validator",
    "dataTableName": "y",
    "dataColumnName": "y",
    "CheckFilter": "CheckBoxFilter",
    "CheckFilterSettings": {
        "values": [
            "70.00"
        ],
        "hierarchyPaths": [

        ]
    }
}

Object.keys(Obj).map((key) => {
  if (key == 'CheckFilterSettings') {
    Obj[key].values[0] == '70.00' ? console.log('value found') : console.log('value not found');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to loop through the object. just simply use es20 feature optional chaining:

```js
var Obj = {
   "testname":"Validator",
   "dataTableName":"y",
   "dataColumnName":"y",
   "CheckFilter":"CheckBoxFilter",
   "CheckFilterSettings":{
      "values":[
         "70.00"
      ],
      "hierarchyPaths":[
         
      ]
   }
}

if(Obj?.CheckFilterSettings?.values?.length>0){
console.log(Obj?.CheckFilterSettings?.values)
}else {
  //whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be simplified, try this...

```
if (Obj.CheckFilterSettings?.values[0] === "70.00"){
    console.log("Value Found");
} else {
    console.log("Value Not Found");
}
```